# How to set up that FastAPI doesn't automatically follow redirect?

Tags: python, fastapi

Is is possible to set up FastApi in such a way that a redirect response will not automatically be followed? Assume I have the following functions:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse

fast_api_app = FastAPI()

@router.get('/some_url')
async def redirect_function():
    redirect_response = RedirectResponse('/redirect_url', status_code=303)

    return redirect_response


@router.get('/redirect_url')
async def redirected_function():
    response = Response(status_code=200)

    return response
```

When I use the requests library or the FastAPI test client to access "/some_url" I always get automatically redirected to "/redirect_url" and the response's status code will be 200. My wished behavior would be that the response status code is 303 and I am responsible for the redirection.

Comment: `allow_redirect=False` for requests calls.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what is was looking for. Thank you! Also works as a kwarg for the FastAPI test client: `client.get(url, allow_redirects=False)`